# For Each loop doesn't break with Try Catch in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

I am writing a simple application that copies files recursively from one directory to another.  The application has a checkbox where the user can choose to overwrite the destination files if they exist.  If the file exists, and overwrite is deselected, then the catch statement should exit the function and return 1, so that the main code can handle the error.

```
        Dim result As Integer
        Dim sourceDirectoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sourcePathHere)
        ' If the destination folder doesn't exist then create it
        If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(destinationPathHere) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPathHere)
        End If
        Dim overwriteHere As Boolean
        If chkOverwrite.Checked = True Then
            overwriteHere = True
        Else
            overwriteHere = False
        End If

        Dim fileSystemInfo As System.IO.FileSystemInfo
        Try
            For Each fileSystemInfo In sourceDirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos
                Dim destinationFileName As String =
                System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPathHere, fileSystemInfo.Name)

                ' Now check whether its a file or a folder and take action accordingly
                If TypeOf fileSystemInfo Is System.IO.FileInfo Then
                    System.IO.File.Copy(fileSystemInfo.FullName, destinationFileName, overwriteHere)
                Else
                    ' Recursively call the mothod to copy all the nested folders
                    CopyDirectory(fileSystemInfo.FullName, destinationFileName)
                End If
            Next
            result = 0
        Catch
            txtStatus.Text = "Error"
            result = 1
        End Try
        'MsgBox(result)  <=For Testing
        Return result
    End Function
```

I would expect that since the catch is outside the for Each loop, once the catch is hit it should set result to 1 and return from the function.  However, when putting a MsgBox there, I'm seeing the box appear 9 times as follows:
1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0

These results don't seem to correspond to my source files at all.

Since the last result is returning 0, the main code completes as if there was no error.  Why isn't my code breaking out of the For Each loop (or maybe something else is happening here)?

There are no other loops in the code calling the function, it is called as follows:

`Dim success As Integer = CopyDirectory(sourcePath, destinationPath)`

Comment: You shouldn't rely on Try/Catch for logic flow. If you already know the two conditions (file exists/overwritehere), then your `If`-`Then` logic should handle it. I don't know the answer to your specific question though.

Comment: As a new user, it will be beneficial to take the [tour], check out [ask] and why [mcve] is important. This is a general comment, and not a reflection on your question.

Comment: Does txtStatus says `error` anyway?

Comment: Can you post the whole function with the function name?

Comment: Why not create a msgbox when existing asking you if you want to replace, if yes then `overwriteHere = True` and copy again with replace then `overwriteHere = false` (to return to normal), if not then skip it. It would be just like windows :)

Comment: Your code is recursive.  When the exception happens, it returns back to the previous iteration of the recursive function and continues the loop in the previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chris Dunaway, the problem was that the function is recursive, so when the Return is called, it just goes up one level of the function but continues. I fixed that by creating an error flag, that once set to true, will persist throughout all the iterations of the function so that it exits gracefully from all of them:

```
Public Function CopyDirectory(ByVal sourcePathHere As String, ByVal destinationPathHere As String, Optional overwriteFiles As Boolean = False, Optional errFlag As Boolean = False) As Boolean
        Dim sourceDirectoryInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sourcePathHere)
        ' If the destination folder doesn't exist then create it
        If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(destinationPathHere) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPathHere)
        End If


        Dim fileSystemInfo As System.IO.FileSystemInfo
       Try
        For Each fileSystemInfo In sourceDirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos


                Dim destinationFileName As String =
                System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPathHere, fileSystemInfo.Name)

                ' Now check whether its a file or a folder and take action accordingly
                If TypeOf fileSystemInfo Is System.IO.FileInfo Then
                    System.IO.File.Copy(fileSystemInfo.FullName, destinationFileName, overwriteFiles)

                Else
                    ' recursive call of the function, accepting the return with the errFlag will stop the function from running again.
                    errFlag = CopyDirectory(fileSystemInfo.FullName, destinationFileName, overwriteFiles, errFlag)
                End If
            Next

        Catch
            txtStatus.Text = "Error"
            errFlag = True
        End Try
        Return errFlag
    End Function
```